# 6.5.3 Classic - Can you add a tooltip to a chart axis label?

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic, extjs6.5

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to add a tooltip of sorts to the chart axis labels? I want to truncate text and show a tooltip when hovering.

this is on Sencha EXT JS 6.5.3 Classic.

Comment: Hi sam, does this maybe help you? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/26qg

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to get the tooltips on the x or y AXIS labels. not the chart data points.

Comment: Hi sam, Did you get how to add tooltip to axis label? Can you post the answer ?

Comment: I did not. I just left it as is.